# Branch Points of a Function with Complex Power

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-points

I'm having problems finding the branch points of this complex function:
$f(z)=z^i$.

I know how to find the branch points of the typical functions:

- $f(z)=z^p$, where $p$ is a rational non-integer. This has branch points at $z=0$ and $z=\infty$.
- $f(z)=\ln(z)$. This has two branch points, also at $z=0$ and $z=\infty$.

Now, for other complex functions that I have come across, the strategy was to convert it into one of those two forms, and work out from there. However, I am having trouble doing this for the function above, where the exponent is an imaginary number.

I have tried converting $z$ using the Euler identity and manipulating with it, but have not been able to get anywhere. Would appreciate some insights or hints on this problem. Thank you!

Edit:

So here's my attempt, not that it got me anywhere.
\begin{align}
\displaystyle f(z)&=\left(r\exp({i\theta})\right)^i \\
&= \left(r\exp({i\theta+2k\pi i}) \right)^i \\
&=r^i \exp(-\theta -2k\pi )
\end{align}

Comment: the branch point should be at zero because the argument changes abrutly there

Comment: @tired hi, thanks for the reply. The reason why I hesitate to come to that conclusion is because we can write $f(z)=\exp(i\ln(z))$ as an alternative expression. Taking $z=0$ would then mean something like (forgive me for sloppiness here): $\exp(-i\infty)$, which is some bounded function, since we can convert it back in terms of $\cos$ and $\sin$. I'm not so sure how to interpret that.